# Visual Studio Express 2012 and Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

Can the IDE level version control support in Visual Studio Express 2012 be used with Git, or would that require plug-in support available only with the full version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Express Editions of Visual Studio 2012: no other plugin supported, except the one (Git Plugin) built by Microsoft.

Comment: Plugin is downloadable here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c and supports Express versions.

Comment: Who downvote? In Dec 2012, no such announcement was made! MS announced this in late Jan 2013!

Comment: @linquize: You're free to update your answer in order to provide the correct information for the new situation.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, the selected answer is wrong. Visual Studio Express 2012 supports Microsoft's plugin for Git, as it's actually an extension of Team Foundation. You can find it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

However as of today there are a couple of bugs in the installer preventing from installing it - this is a bug, and will be addressed in a future release (check the comments of the project to see Microsoft's response).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TortoiseGit? I know the preferred choice would be to use a plugin but with the Express is not possible. It happened to me with Ankhsvn when I started with the Express. I don't know if it is a good tool, you can give it a go: https://tortoisegit.org/